# Wamp server #2002 error

Tags: php

I am not sure how am I supposed to solve this problem:

```
#2002 - The server is not
responding (or the local
MySQL server's socket is
not correctly configured)
```

Comment: What's the colour of WAMPServer icon?

Comment: Check what's happening with the port 3306.

Comment: the port is 3306 at config

Comment: That's right... Can you check if the MySQL is really running by clicking on the WampServer icon » MySQL » Service?

Comment: i start msql service but it did not start....

Comment: Try changing the port number to something else other than 3306.

Comment: i have try it...noy working

Comment: Try executing `mysqld` in `cmd` and tell me what's the output you are getting or if there's any error? You need to go to the `C:\Wamp\bin\mysql\(version)\bin` and then execute `mysqld`.

Comment: it open blank cmd page

Comment: it change the error msg to cant connect invalid settings

Comment: yes....what will i do to solve that

Comment: Try looking at the dupe. Click on that link and see?